# WordPress Options Page: Get "Name" and "Value" for Select

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Here's my code for the options page:

```
array(
    "name" => "Background Image",
    "desc" => "Select your background image.",
    "id" => $shortname."_blog_background",
    "type" => "select",
    "options" => array("Light Wood", "Dark Wood"),
    "std" => ""
),
```

The select will show and will return the values inside the array. Is there a way to show "Light Wood", but to return "light-wood.png" ? I tried this:

```
"options" => array(
   array('name' => 'Light Wood', 'value' => 'light-wood.png'),
   array('name' => 'Dark Wood', 'value' => 'dark-wood.pn')
),
```

but it returns "Array".

Comment: How are you calling the object in your array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
<select name="">
    <option value="light-wood.png">Light Wood</option>
    <option value="dark-wood.png">Dark Wood</option>
</select>
```

Then the code should be:

```
<select>
    <?php foreach($options as $option) echo "<option value=\"{$option[value]}\">{$option[name]}</option>"; ?>
</select>
```

Or, is there like a form generator that will create the HTML automatically? Then you can try (but I'm just guessing):

```
"options" => array(
   array('Light Wood'=> 'light-wood.png'),
   array('Dark Wood' => 'dark-wood.png'),
),
```

Or interchange 'light-wood.png' => 'Light Wood'.